# How to send $http.get request every second from service

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-services

I have an angular application which has $htto.get request it works fine but I need to execute it every one second to bring new data.

Service:

```
angular.module('adf.widget.liveCharts')
  .service('liveChartService', function($q, $http, $timeout){

    return {
      getJSON: function(path){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var url = 'http://orbit5.ds.cs.umu.se:8888/vrio/blk';
        $http.get(url)
          .success(function(data){
            if (data){
              deferred.resolve(data);
              } else {
                deferred.reject(data.data.message);
              }
            })
          .error(function(){
            deferred.reject();
          });
        return deferred.promise;
      }
  }
  });
```

adding controller here for reference

```
angular.module('adf.widget.liveCharts', ['adf.provider', 'highcharts-ng'])
  .config(function(dashboardProvider){
    // template object for github widgets
    var widget = {
      templateUrl: '{widgetsPath}/liveCharts/src/view.html',
      reload: true,
      resolve: {
        /* @ngInject */
        paths: function(liveChartService, config, $timeout){
          if (config.path){
            return liveChartService.getJSON(config.path);
          }

        }
      },
      edit: {
        templateUrl: '{widgetsPath}/liveCharts/src/edit.html'
      }
    };
```

Comment: What's wrong with $timeout?

Comment: If you need updated data that frequently, you should probably be looking at websockets instead.

Comment: I dont know how to impliment timeout properly with this code if I add $timeout(function(path)... , 1000) then I get an error liveChartService.getJSON is not a function from my controller.. also adding controller above

Comment: This is not what Angular is created for. I strongly recommened you NOT to use any kind of hacks/workarounds to get your data like this. Search for SingleR, it will suits better for your needs.

Comment: could you add a link to singleR

Comment: perhaps he meant `signalR` ?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller do like this.

```
$interval(function(){

    liveChartService.getJSON().then(function(data){

        //$scope.data = data;
    })
},1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **$interval** can help you - It's very similar to setInterval in vanilla js - Basically this is the structure

$interval(fn, delay, [count], [invokeApply], [Pass]);

the last 3 parameters are optional, but you need to pass the function + delay time in milliseconds, you can use any function there, or call a function that return another function:

```
$interval(function(){
    liveChartService.getJSON().then(function(data){
        //some codes here
    })
},1000);
```

Hope it helps you...